# Leader and Follower configuration in Zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am wondering where in Zookeeper do I have to configure my follower and my leader?
When I have this in my config file:

`server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
server.3=zoo3:2888:3888`

Which one is the leader which are the followers? Or is this part of the leader election?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the internal leader election. Those servers decide amongst themselves who is going to lead/follow.

Answer (score 2):

Any server in a zookeeper can become the leader at any time.  If the current leader goes down, or a majority of servers can't connect to it, a new leader will be elected.

The only exception is [observers](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperObservers.html).